# Cannot copy airflow.cfg

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, airflow-webserver

I would like to extract the 'airflow.cfg' file from docker container to make an easy access to configuration. I tried everything but I cannot copy this particular file.

The last volume creates  only folder airflow.cfg ...

```
   volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ./config/airflow.cfg:/opt/airflow/airflow.cfg
```

I can copy the entire folder with path:

```
- `./config/:/opt/airflow/`
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8snLI.png)

but not just the airflow.cfg file...

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default,
 `- ./config/airflow.cfg:/opt/airflow/airflow.cfg`

will create a folder;

try reading the file airflow.cfg from the docker using `docker exec -it <docker container name> cat /opt/airflow/airflow.cfg` and create the file `./config/airflow` this way the volume will not create any folder and you could then for use this file to edit your in docker file

Comment: Ok, I am in airflow.cfg in docker, but I don't get the rest of hint. Shoud I create `./config/airflow` inside docker or in my 'external' folder ?